# How to know if the added data to angularjs not saved to firebase databse if no internet connection

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When i try to add data via form using firebase array it gets added and displayed immediately on the screen and firebase database but if i disable my internet connection and try to add data it's added in the angular application but not in the firebase database so how to know that added data isn't saved to database.

```
Nodes.$add(preparedNode)
            .then(function (lastAddedNode ) {
                console.log( 'lastAddedNode', lastAddedNode );
                console.log( 'key()', lastAddedNode.key() );
                $scope.node.name = '';
                feedbackMessages.success();
            })
```

then is called only when the data is saved to firebase database i need to know if it isn't added maybe because internet connection or any problem i need this problem to display it to the user.
Any help ?

Comment: What does the `.catch` method return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase will ensure the data gets saved when the connection gets restored. For that reason the requirement "I need to know when the data isn't saved" doesn't really fit in Firebase's model.

You can handle a few cases though:

1. detect when the application is not connected to the Firebase back-end
2. detect when saving the data takes longer then expected

To **detect whether the application is connected to the Firebase back-end**, you can use this [example from the Firebase documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/offline-capabilities.html#section-connection-state):

> For many presence-related features, it is useful for a client to know when it is online or offline. Firebase clients provide a special location at `/.info/connected`, which is updated every time the client's connection state changes. Here is an example:

```
var connectedRef = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/.info/connected");
connectedRef.on("value", function(snap) {
  if (snap.val() === true) {
    alert("connected");
  } else {
    alert("not connected");
  }
});
```

> `/.info/connected` is a boolean values which is not synchronized between clients because the values are dependent on the state of the client. In other words, if one client reads `/.info/connected` as false, this is no guarantee that a separate client will also read false.

This uses the Firebase JavaScript SDK. Since AngularFire is built on top of that SDK, the two interoperate seamlessly.

To *detect when saving data takes longer than expected** you'd use a `setTimer()`. Start it when you start saving the data, reset it when the promise resolves (in `then()`) and if the timer expires: do your "data hasn't saved" handling.

Just be aware that Firebase will still have the data queued to be saved. So when the connection to the server is restored, it will still save the data.

Comment: Thank you a lot :) :) :) 
detect when the application is not connected to the Firebase back-end is responding faster. Actually it takes about 2 or 3 seconds to log connected or not :D. I will try method number 2 later. 
Thanks again